# Transformer secondary wired to primary and secondary of second transformer

Tags: ac, transformer, ethernet, magnetics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fro4Y4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I see something like this for ethernet, and it confuses me. What is it for? What does it do? Could I remove that from the schematic?

Comment: Google common-mode filter

Comment: @brhans, googled, is it for differential signals so they add up to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like brhans said, it's a common mode filter for EMI suppression. You need to measure both emissions and immunity before you can say if it's required or not in this particular application.

Comment: Note that this CM filter was for older style ethernet with a limit of 100Mbps. Also this is not PoE compatible-it has no center tap on the cable side.